# Rellenar un array con contenido de otro array

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Muy buenos días, tengo un error al momento de rellenar un array con el contenido de otros dos arrays, el error sería que al mostrar el contenido del array_3 solo me aparece que se ha rellenado con la última posición del primer array. Mi código sería el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejercicio_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tamano = 0, tamano_2 = 0, tamano_3 = 0;
    System.out.println("¿De que tamañano quieres que sea la primera lista?");
    tamano = sn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("¿De que tamañano quieres que sea la segunda lista?");
    tamano_2 = sn.nextInt();
    
    tamano_3 = tamano + tamano_2;
    
    int [] numeros = new int [tamano];
    int [] numeros_2 = new int [tamano_2];
    int [] numeros_3 = new int [tamano_3];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un número para meterlo en la lista 1:");
        numeros[i] = sn.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros_2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un número para meterlo en la lista 2:");
        numeros_2[i] = sn.nextInt();
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros_3.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
            numeros_3[i] = numeros[j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros_3.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numeros_2.length; j++) {
            numeros_3[i] = numeros_2[j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros_3.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numeros_3[i]);
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: En el bucle donde estás metiendo los elementos de `numeros_2` en `numeros_3` no puedes inicializar `i` a 0, porque entonces machacas lo que habias escrito antes. Tienes que inicializar `i` a `numeros.length` para que siga escribiendo sin machacar lo que ya tenías.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes mal enfocados los `for` en los que añades todo al tercer array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numeros_3.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
        numeros_3[i] = numeros[j];
    }
}
```

En ese código, recorremos primero de `i = 0` hasta la longitud del tercer array, y por cada vuelta de ese `for`, otro `for` de `j = 0` hasta la longitud del primer array. Esto no tiene sentido. Estás metiendo en el tercer array, en la posición `i` todos los elementos del primer array. Todos uno a uno. Al final solo el último se queda puesto. Y eso para `i = 0`. Para `i = 1`, haces lo mismo. Metes todos uno a uno del primer array en la posición 1 del tercer array. Y al final se queda el último otra vez. Resultado: array tercero tiene en todas sus posiciones el último elemento del primer array.

Solo te hace falta un `for`, de `i = 0` hasta el número de elementos del primer array:

```
int = 0;
for( i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
    numeros_3[i] = numeros[i];
}
```

Fíjate que la la `i` está definida fuera del `for` y es para poder continuar ahora con el segundo `for` que iría a continuación y usaría esa misma variable `i`:

```
for( int j = 0; j < tamano_2; j++) {
    numeros_3[ i + j] = numeros_2[j];
}
```

Sigues introduciendo números en el tercer array desde el mismo punto donde lo dejaste en el primer `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Estas muy cerca de la respuesta.

Aqui te dejo 2 opciones para que puedas completar y solucionar el problema:

#### Opción # 1

No es necesario tener `for` anidados, puedes usar la variable del for para acceder a ambos indices de los arreglos.

```java
// #1
for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
     numeros_3[i] = numeros[i];
}

// #2
for (int i = tamano; i < tamano_3; i++) {
      numeros_3[i] = numeros_2[i - tamano];
}

for (int i = 0; i < numeros_3.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(numeros_3[i]);
}
```

En el #1 recorres los datos de arreglo `numeros` normal y copias en el arreglo `numeros_3`.
Luego en #2 lo que debes iniciar el arreglo desde esa posición usando `tamano` y en la variable del arreglo `tamano_2` le indicas `i - tamano` para poder acceder desde 0 a la posicion del arreglo 2.

Es valido en este caso también.

```
for ( int j = 0; j < tamano_2; j++ ) {
    numeros_3[ i + j] = numeros_2[j];
}
```

#### Opción 2

Puedes usar clases de utilerias de Java como `System.arraycopy`, ejemplo:

```java
System.arraycopy(numeros, 0, numeros_3, 0, tamano);
System.arraycopy(numeros_2, 0, numeros_3, tamano, tamano_2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros_3));
```

Comment: Me parece que la opción dos depende de la versión de Java que tenga instalada

Comment: @RuslanLópez veo que esta disponible en la versión 7
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Exactamente, sufrió cambios en versiones posteriores