# Copiar datos de un array a otro en Java

Tags: java

Hola necesito ayuda para la siguiente tarea.
Tengo que crear un array de la siguiente manera:

```
char b[]={'h','o','l','a'};
```

Y en un array nuevo copiar esos datos y mostrar el array nuevo. Aquí dejo lo que tengo por ahora.

```
public class arrayHola {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        char b[]={'h','o','l','a'};
        char c[]= new char[b.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Rellenar un array con contenido de otro array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399665/rellenar-un-array-con-contenido-de-otro-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he conseguido lo que buscaba con el siguiente codigo:

```
public class arrayHola {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        char b[]={'h','o','l','a'};
        char c[]= new char[b.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i <b.length ; i++) {
            c[i] = b[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<b.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```